# int? version available for String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Tags: c#, extension-methods, nullable

Our application requires `int?` variables. I'm often checking both to make sure not null and not 0 and it does get lengthy.

Is there an out of the box version of `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` or `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` for `int?`

Maybe this would require an extension method?

If there even was or when someone makes one, would something like this considered bad practice?

Comment: you can make an extension for it but I would just name it nicely,  HasNonDefaultValue

Comment: Or even `(x ?? 0) == 0`

Comment: and this isn't considered terrible practice laced with an unholy deathwish? I feel like anytime I suggest some extension I get reamed on here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so but it's easy to write your own:

```
[Pure]
public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this T? pValue)
where T : struct {
   return pValue == null || pValue.Value.Equals(default(T));

   // or as suggested in comments (tested)
   return pValue == null || EqualityComparer<T?>.Default.Equals(pValue, default(T));
}
```

Comment: As a side note, consider using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` to avoid the boxing incurred by calling `Object.Equals`.